# display of elements of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

1. I was trying to print four numbers from a two dimension array that are in adjacent rows and columns. Numbers entered in the array were:

   ```
       404 414 424 434 444
       505 506 507 508 509
       312 313 314 315 316
       822 823 824 825 826
   ```
2. I wanted  output of

   ```
       row1,col2; row1,col3 
       row2,col2; row2,col3
   ```
3. The display I have got is

   ```
       507508
       314315
   ```
4. I wanted the display as

   ```
       507 508
       314 315
   ```
5. The code for display that I had written is:

   ```
     Console. Write Line("Values =>" +array[row,col]  +array[row,col1] );

     Console. Write Line("Values =>" +array[row1,col]  +array[row1,col1]  );
   ```
6. I tried putting double ampersands, double quotes to increase spaces between +array[row,col] and +array[row,col1] to obtain the display I wanted. I treated also the next line of the code similarly. Double ampersands and double quotes did not change the display; it remained as shown at para 3 above with both changes.

&. How do I get the display as shown at para 4? Help please.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
"Values =>" +array[row,col]  +array[row,col1]
```

You are concatenating the values of the array cells directly together without any spaces.

You need to add a space between them:

```
"Values =>" + array[row,col] + " " + array[row,col1]
```

A better approach is to use [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), where the space is embedded in the formatting string:

```
Console.WriteLine("Values => {0} {1}", array[row,col], array[row,col1]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I had tried the pair of double-quotes, but did not put the + sign before the double-quotes. This is exactly what I was wanting to do! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, by adding a space:

```
Console.WriteLine("Values =>" +array[row1,col]  + " " + array[row1,col1]  );
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked. I missed the + sign before the pair of double-quotes. God Bless you..thanks once again..... Colonel Rajdhan

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("Values => {0} {1}", array[row,col], array[row,col1]);
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked. I was not very familiar with this way of doing . God Bless you..thanks once again..... Colonel Rajdhan –

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Join as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array[row, col], array[row, col]));
```

It's easier to add more array elements.

However it will be more efficient to use jagged arrays (if it's possible). The same task is simpler allowing you to use row ranges and col ranges. Check the draft example.

```
// your array as jagged array
int[][] jtest = { 
    new int[] { 404, 414, 424, 434, 444 }, 
    new int[] { 505, 506, 507, 508, 509 }, 
    new int[] { 312, 313, 314, 315, 316 }, 
    new int[] { 822, 823, 824, 825, 826 } 
    };

// definitions for row ranges
int firstRow = 1; int lastRow = 2;
// definitions for col ranges
int firstCol = 2; int lastCol = 3;
// int array for copying row elements in col range
int[] dump = new int[lastCol - firstCol + 1];

// do it
for (var i = firstRow; i <= lastRow; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(jtest[i], firstCol, dump, 0, dump.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dump));
}
```